# Internal memory crash from NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle call

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory, localization, nsbundle

I have a call to `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle` which typically works, so I know it has the right parameters for key, table, & bundle name. However, after another, seemingly unrelated operation X is done in the app, and the same "string from bundle" call is made, I get crash. The stack trace only shows `[NSBundle localizedStringForKey:value:table:]`.

```
*** -[CFDictionary objectForKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4e6f2d0
```

I used Instruments, and it doesn't show anything unusual until the crash itself, where it indeed finds a zombie.

1   0x7a2f840   CFDictionary (mutable)  Zombie  -1  00:51.528.884   0   Foundation  -[NSBundle _initInfoDictionary]

Other things I've tried include replacing the macro call to explicitly loading the bundle using `[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:`. Again, this works until other operation X is done, and then same crash, although in this case it's on the load call I added.

```
    if (![bundle isLoaded])
        [bundle load];
```

Although you can already tell it's not going to work by that point, as typically the description of the bundle is valid (`NSBundle </Users/...blah...framework> (loaded)`), but when it's not going to work, it just looks like this:

```
(NSBundle *) $3 = 0x0613f020 NSBundle <(null)> (not yet loaded)
```

The obvious answer is that operation X does something bad, but I cannot see anything that it would do, save using some of its own autorelease pools (on 10.8). It fails even when I comment those out though. And still, let's say I had bad code there, how could I mess up the internal init or load for NSBundle in this very particular way so that it becomes unusable for localization?

Has anyone ever seen something like it? I really want it to be something I'm doing wrong, and not just a problem on 10.8 (does not happen on 10.6, btw).